# Long-term durability of linen vs polyamide vs polyester?

Tags: polymers, materials

What is the comparative long-term durability of linen vs polyamide vs polyester when exposed to oxygen, but not sunlight?

I assume that linen, polyamides (Nylon) and polyesters will all oxidize and become brittle over long periods of time (decades). What is the comparative longevity of the three materials in this regard?